# Difference between BigQuery API and BigQuery Storage API?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the difference between the [BigQuery API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) and [BigQuery Storage API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries)?

In the Overview section of BigQuery Storage Read API, it says

> The BigQuery Storage Read API provides fast access to BigQuery-managed storage by using an rpc-based protocol.

Is BigQuery Storage API just faster because it uses rpc?

Comment: Mabel's answer below covers the differences.  The BigQuery Storage API is faster for high throughput use-cases because it was designed explicitly to handle them.  This allows for parallelizing reads and more efficient data serialization formats (Arrow and Avro instead of JSON) in addition to the being streaming RPC based which cuts down on overhead due to multiple request paging).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are correct it is fast since it uses rpc, and also as stated in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#background),

> The Storage Read API does not provide functionality related to managing BigQuery resources such as datasets, jobs, or tables.

Basically, you would want to use [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries-overview#storage_api) on top of BigQuery API when your operation requires the need to scan large volumes of managed data as it exposes high throughput data reading for consumers. Otherwise, use of [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries-overview#api) is enough for interactions with core resources such as datasets, tables, jobs, and routines.

For further reading, see this documentations on some of the key features of [Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#advantages) and [Storage Read API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#key_features).

Comment: Is it possible to provide sql select query in Storage Read Api ?

Comment: @1stenjoydmoment No, only simple column selection and simple filtering. (no calculations / subqueries / etc.)